# AngularJS Set Date Format to "MM/YYYY" After Enter the Date

Tags: angularjs, date, format

Text field should allow only numeric , after enters number then i should convert the field values in DD/YY format.

JS :

```
app.controller('ctrlCreditPayment', function ($scope, $filter, $http, ngDialog,creditCard) {
$filter('cardexp')(new Date(), dd/yyyy);
});
```

HTML :

```
<input size="8" class="card-exp input-mid" placeholder="MM/YYYY" required type="text"  ng-model="cardexp">
```

Code Pen:
https://codepen.io/fareed543-1472110535/pen/jAjGkq

Comment: can you post the text field?

Comment: I think you should go through this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think this answer is correct, but i got a temporary solution by using ui-mask. which allow number and allow to define the format

```
<input type="text" ng-model="cardexp" ui-mask="9?9/9?9?9?9">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
**Js**
`$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)`

i.e `$filter('cardexp')(new Date(), dd/yyyy, UTC)`
Note:- Make sure you have proper data in `'cardexp'`

Then use `cardexp` in `ng-model`
Like - `<input size="8" class="card-exp input-mid" placeholder="MM/YYYY" required type="text"  ng-model="cardexp">`

And You can use directly using angular date format,go through the link below:-
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: @MohammadFareed I updated my answer may be it will help you.

Comment: yes obviously it will not work because you added filter in `ng-model`. dont use ` | date:......`, USE `ng-model="cardexp".
you can not add filter in `ng-model`, you can add it only in expressions or if you dont want to add it in expression then use it in JS using `$filter`